# Display contents from a PDF on Web browser on a machine where PDF Reader/Viewer is not installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, plugins

I want to design an application using ASP.Net MVC which will allow me to display the contents from PDF on a Web browser. This should happen without any problem even on the machines where the PDF Reader/Viewer is not installed.

I was thinking of converting PDF to image and then displaying, but I believe there will be more efficient ways/plugins with which this can be achieved.

Please let me know the ways to do it.

Comment: what's wrong with <object type="application/data" data="file1.pdf"><iframe src="some_mozillas_pdfjs_viewer.html?file=file1.pdf></iframe></object> ?

Answer (score 2):

Short of making all your users use Chrome, which has built-in PDF display, there's nothing that can be done. PDF is a proprietary file format, and as such needs some sort of viewer installed on the machine in order to see it. What you're talking about is like asking how you can open an Excel file without having to have Excel or some other program capable of reading it like LibreOffice installed. It's simply not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about Chrome.
Actually, I don't want to place any browser restriction. I want to allow users to use any of the major browsers (like IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc). Users may even be accessing the application from tablet.

Comment: Hence, I wanted to know if there is some plugin available which will help me do this or I have to go for something like converting pdf to some image format and then displaying the image(s)?

Comment: +1 for letting me know about build-in PDF display for Chrome. I think, same is true with Mozilla Firefox too.

Answer (score 0):

In View:

`<object data="@Url.Action("Showpdf", "ControllerName")"></object>`

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Showpdf()
    {
        return File("FilePath", "application/pdf");
    }
```

In Order to display pdf from a DB or something, you can use

```
public ActionResult Showpdf()
    {
        byte[] pdf = getPdfFromDbOrSomewhereElse();
        return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
    }
```